# Wordpress - Call add_filter inside a function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I call a function (function is placed in theme functions.php) from my template. This function should call add_filter body_class. "Try to call add filter" is printed but add_filter will not work. When I use the add_filter outside the function it will work. Both ways here are not working :/

Way 1

```
add_action('test_callback_add_no_hero_class', 'test_callback_add_no_hero_class_funct');
function test_callback_add_no_hero_class_funct() {
    echo 'Try to call add filter';
    add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
        return array_merge( $classes, array( 'pxlr-site-no-hero' ) );
    } );
}

//do_action('test_callback_add_no_hero_class'); // call from my template
```

Way 2

```
add_action('test_callback_add_no_hero_class', 'test_callback_add_no_hero_class_funct');
function test_callback_add_no_hero_class_funct() {
    echo 'Try to call add filter';
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'pxlr_nohero_custom_class' );
}

function pxlr_nohero_custom_class( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'pxlr-site-no-hero';
    return $classes;
}

//do_action('test_callback_add_no_hero_class'); // call from my template
```

Comment: What hook is `test_callback_add_no_hero_class` are you just making it up, or is there some kind of theme hook with that name?

Comment: thats my custom hook (some test name), I can call do_action('test_callback_add_no_hero_class'); inside my template file

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with the snippet code in way 1. The filter isn't working because of the action call. `test_callback_add_no_hero_class` action, should run before the [`apply_filters`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/).

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand what you mean correctly. I think I have an understanding problem using my function and how to call them straight out of my template :-/